# Showing that negative iterates of the following map converge exponentially to $\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map such that all eigenvalues have absolute values less than 1. I'm trying to show that if $A$ is an invertible map, i.e if zero is not an eigenvalue of $A$, then negative iterates of every point go to infinity exponentially.

Can someone give me a hint?

P. S. We know that since all eigenvalues have absolute values less than 1, then $A$ is a contraction.

Comment: Hint: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $1/ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Hint: what are the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$?